# How to connect to / edit files on 12.04 guest from Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, file-sharing

I would like to have the following setup, but I don't really know where to start looking or if it is even possible:

- Windows 7 is the host Operating System
- Ubuntu 12.04 guest Operating System is running development server in Virtual box.

I would like to be able to edit files on 12.04, using sublime text 2 on Windows 7. Also like to be able to view the dev website using a web browser on Windows 7.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long answers:

1. Yes, VirtualBox **supports a feature which allows a certain folder to be shared** between the guest and the host os. You just drag and drop from windows anything you might want in that folder, and you will be able to see it inside the guest.
   [image]
2. Yes, If you set up your virtual machine's networking mode to **bridged mode**, then you will be able to use a browser to access it. To be more specific, **if you have set up a web server** in your virtual machine, and let's say the virtual machine's internal ip address is `192.168.1.3`, then just fire **Chrome** (or **Firefox**, or anything for that sake) and **type in the address field the ip address**.
   [image]

Comment: About the first answer: I think the question is about editing the files that are in the gues, from the host. And your question is about the inverse way.

Answer (score 2):

couldnt you just configure samba on the linux machine and make a folder a windows share?  Not sure why you would need to get so complicated.